# Edit /Update values from 2 tables

Tags: javascript, laravel, crud

I have a form whose data comes from 2 tables.

[image]

Now i need some help to make the edit function, because i can't display the data.
In the edit function I need to make something like:
***Select * from *category* and *semantic* where *category*.category_id=$category_id and *semantic*.table_mr="Person"***

For the update i also need some help to update the semantic table(category is already done).

> EditForm:

```html
        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      Edit category
        <form method="post" action="{{ url('category/update-category/') }}">
         @csrf
         @method('PUT')
          <input type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_id">
           Category name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
           Table model: <input type="text" id="ontology" name="ontology">
          Class: <input type="text" id="seClass" name="seClass">
              <button type="submit" >Update</button>
              <button type="button" >Close</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.editbtn', function(){
            var category_id=$(this).val();
               $('#editModal').modal('show');
          $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url:"../category/edit-category/"+category_id,
              success: function(response){     
                  
                     $('#name').val(response.category.name);
                     $('#ontology').val(response.category.semanticOntology);
                     $('#seClass').val(response.category.semantiClass);
                    $('#category_id').val(category_id);        
              }
          });
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

> Controller:

```php
    public function edit(**$category_id**){
       $category=category::with('semantic')->find($category_id);
     
 
    return response()->json([
     'category'=>$category,
    ]);  
    }

    public function update(Request $request){
        $category_id=$request->input('category_id');
        $category = category::find($category_id);
        $category->name = $request->input('name');
        $category->update ();
         // $semantic->Dont know how to make it
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Updated with success');
    }
```

> Class Category:

```php
    class category extends Model{
        protected $table = "category";
        protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
        public $timestamps = false;
        use HasFactory;
        protected $sql=['category_id','name'];
    
    
        public function semantic(){       
            return $this->belongsTo('App\models\semantic', 'category_id', 'idtable_record');      
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you would like to save your model and all of its associated relationships, you may use the `push` method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-push-method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the Laravel framework (v8.61.0 at least):

```
 public function edit(**$category_id**){
   $category=category::withRelation('semantic', $category_id);
 

return response()->json([
 'category'=>$category,
]);  
}
```

Review this line: (Category)

```
$category = Category::find($category_id);
```

For update method, you can use the app model binding by passing arguments in the route url.
Example:

```
Route::post('/category/{category}', [your action]);
```